# MySQL select field from array of JSON objects

Tags: mysql, json

So i have in my database a column = `foo_ids` and its content is as follows: 
 `[{"id": "432"}, {"id": "433"}]`

question is what query will give me back as a result all of the id's in this field?

out of several attempts my last one was
 `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(foo_ids,'$.id') FROM foo_table`
but clearly it didn't work...any idea?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Comment: `Unless otherwise indicated, the JSON functions were added in MySQL 5.7.8.`, see [12.16 JSON Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-functions.html).

Comment: the solution @83N  suggested worked for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want to return an array of the ID's you could do this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(foo_ids, '$**.id') FROM foo_table;
```

The `*` wildcard evaluates each json object in an array.

Comment: Is there a way to return the array where id = 432 for example?

Comment: Yes, by doing something along the lines of `SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(foo_ids, '$**.id') FROM foo_table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(foo_ids, '{ "id" : "432" }');`  -  check out the MySQL docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html)

Comment: This only works where the id is a string and not an int as such. '{ "id" : "432" }' will work but '{ "id" : 432 }' won't as it returns all items