# How to query dictionary type column values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table looking like:

```
uuid  investors
1     [{"type": "Organization", "uuid": "435847ec34f541c3b66615de1f346534"}, {"type": "Organization", "uuid": "8bad8a2d97ba4d3c716686244058858e"}]
2     [{"type": "Person", "uuid": "9603633439264ebfb3e46e6052055893"}, {"type": "Organization", "uuid": "a3734663f2d34893afeeda74da26683a"}]
```

I want to query the `uuid` inside the list of column `investors` based on if it is `Organization` and `Person` as I have to later look for those `uuid` in these tables.

**EDIT**

thanks to @tcadidot0's answer, I now can get two columns containing `type` value and `uuid` value. Here is a screenshot of the results. Now, based on `type`, I want to access the corresponding tables and get the whole row having this particular `uuid`. Following is how the tables, `Organization` and `Person` looks like:

## ORGANIZATION TABLE

```
uuid                              name
435847ec34f541c3b66615de1f346534  XYZ
```

## PERSON TABLE

```
uuid                              name
9603633439264ebfb3e46e6052055893  Bob
```

[image]

Comment: Show us your attempted query

Comment: I have no idea actually, I tried subquerying but I think it is not for my case.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @Cid I want to get `uuid` from the column `investors` and must know if it has `type`: `Organization` or `Person`

Comment: This doesn't tell what should the expected output be. `SELECT investors FROM yourTable` will give you that result

Comment: This will give me all the values in this column, for ex., `[{"type": "Organization", "uuid": "435847ec34f541c3b66615de1f346534"}, {"type": "Organization", "uuid": "8bad8a2d97ba4d3c716686244058858e"}]`. But I want the value `uuid` that's inside these square brackets.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60560254/edit) your question and show us what should be the result of that query, given the sample input

Comment: @Cid I edited my question, please have a look. Thank you!

Comment: So, what you mean from the first find of `uuid` and `type`, you're going to use it to lookup the `uuid` from corresponding table name that match with `type`? Something like `IF type = 'Organization' THEN run this query (SELECT * FROM Organization WHERE uuid='xxxxxx') , IF type = 'Person' THEN run this query (SELECT * FROM Person WHERE uuid='xxxxxx')`?

Answer (score 2):

I see your data is `JSON`. Try this query :

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(investors, '$**.uuid') AS `uuid`,
       JSON_EXTRACT(investors, '$**.type') AS `Type`
FROM   mytable;
```

Like in this fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8roowVBt5VY6AebWHav9hb/1

I got this answer partially from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45671728/10910692

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me give it a try.

Comment: This works and returns two columns, `uuid`&`Type`, now I want to look for this `uuid` in other table named `Organization` or `Person`. Can I do that using subquerying? or is there a better way? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly but you can add `WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(investors, '$**.type') LIKE '%Person%'` or something like that. I think with this example you can edit your question with your expected output to make us better understand. Just make a screenshot on spreadsheet etc. to illustrate how do you want the result returned.

Comment: Thank you again. I edited my question, please have a look.